# Boto3 - Metadata token is different to Session get_credentials token

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

Boto3: EC2 Metadata token does not match Boto3 token

`curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/role-name`

returns a particular token.
 `"Token" : "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"`

Now to see if boto3 uses the same token as listed in metadata:

`python3`
`import boto3`
`session = boto3.Session()`
`session = boto3.Session().get_credentials().token`

`'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'`

returns a DIFFERENT token to the EC2 Metadata, even checking the EC2 metadata again after via curl.. it is still different.

If the IAM role is removed from the EC2 instance, the boto3 session stops being able to get credentials. As soon as IAM role is re-added then boto3 session can get credentials. This is proof that the boto3 is utilising the EC2 metadata credentials. So why in the world is the metadata token different to the boto3 token if boto3 is supposed to use the metadata token?
Input appreciated - I am contempt that boto3 works but trying to understand exactly what is happening under the hood.

Comment: What happens if you call the endpoint multiple times? Do you get the same token or different tokens? Why would you assume boto3 to retrieve the same temporary credentials as your own `curl` call.

Comment: Continuously creating new boto3 sessions keeps returning the same token over and over. My understanding was that boto3 is essentially curling the metadata at the time to get it's token. If this is not the case, then what is the point of being able to curl the metadata if it isnt even being used?

Per Boto3 doc: "If you are running on Amazon EC2 and no credentials have been found by any of the providers above, Boto3 will try to load credentials from the instance metadata service"

Comment: That wasn't my question. My question was what happens if *you* curl repeatedly... Boto obviously caches the retrieved credentials but does not have access to the credentials you previously retrieved.

Comment: Repeated curls to the metadata keeps returning the same information

Answer (score 0):

Self answered question:

It turns out that IMDSv2 and IMDSv1 actually have different credentials when you curl.
This doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/configuring-instance-metadata-service.html outlines how to create the token to use IMDSv2 and the output of this curl is exactly the credentials that Boto3 will use.